# Is it possible/wise to NOT link any pages from index? (SEO, Search Engines)

Tags: seo, search-engine

I have a humble question :)

i plan to set up a rather unusual webproject with about a thousand pages, where there won't be a classical navigation (only for about page and contact) and all pages won't link to one and another.

its index > opens random page > opens random page > opens random page.. all via a small php action..

i know from basic SEO understanding, that you should then generate a static directory like a sitemap, that links to all pages, so that google finds all pages from the index downwards..

BUT i don't want users, to see it.. it kills the fun on using the site, when you can see all content pages at a glance.. this project is all about exploring random things..

is this somehow possible? to have a dead end index page and a thousand dead end html pages that are only connected via a php script?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a technical standpoint, there are no issues in what you are planning. From a SEO indexing and Google standpoint, make sure none of the pages you want discovered and indexed by Google are orphans, i.e. without a link to these pages.

These "hidden" pages need not be linked from the home page or a sitemap (one-to-many), instead you can try the breadcrumb method where a page leads only to the next page, which leads to the next page (one-to-one) and so on. 
e.g. -

Parent 1 > child 1 > child 1a > child 1b .......

Parent 2 > child 2 > child 2a > child 2b .......

Parent 3 > child 3 > child 3a > child 3b .......

Here, the home page and your sitemap will have links ONLY to Parent 1, Parent 2 & Parent 3

**UPDATE**--
Also, not having a HTML sitemap for your users will not affect Google indexing as long as your XML sitemap is in place for Google to access.
Hope this helps.

Comment: hey @masmrdrr thanks again for you answer.. i like your idea, but it does not fully solve my problem because i didn't wanted to link the pages.. the flow should have been: index page > random orphan page > random orphan page.. all via a custom build php action.. so no static links..

Comment: maybe i need a div at the botton then with links to a few "similar" pages.. but i wanted this for a much later version.. first i wanted to just have a single use case.. one button, refresh.. click refresh.. thats all..

Comment: to understand it a bit better.. the problem is not, that i can't find a way to somehow link something.. it just would kill the productidea somehow.. so its a rather uncommon problem i guess.. for the user i have a dynamic linkage but google doesn't sees it.. if i add static links to match google requirements, i would have a bader user experience..

Answer (score 0):

There's not technical problem in having one page generate links to other pages upon generation, but I feel like there are some issues in the general idea here..

Firstly, why do you want your "sub pages" to be indexed by Google? Per definition, this defeats the "random page" idea. A Google search over your site (for instance using the "site:" feature of Google) will list all your pages, since they're indexed. This means it is easy to navigate between the "secret pages" (even if only cached versions of them).

Secondly, unless you prevent Google from indexing your pages (via a robots.txt file, for instance) - the Google bot will generate at least a subset of your pages by visiting the index page and then generating a link to a sub page.

To conclude, you can create an index which sends users over to random pages, but it probably makes little sense to have the web site indexed by a search engine if you'd like the sub pages to be "secret".

Comment: Hello Jonatan, thanks for your quick answer.. i don't want the pages to be "secret".. all thousand pages should be indexed by google, to be found via searches.. i just don't want users, to see all pages on a sitemap page.. it will take the fun away, to know, the whole content by just one click.. its OK, if tech geeks can find it out anyway, but the regular users should have fun in exploring..

Comment: the only problem i have is, that the single pages are not linked anywhere and as i understood it, all pages need to be linked from the index.. or have i understood this wrong? does google scann ALL html pages by nature.. even if they are NOT linked?

Comment: @MG1974 Google cannot access orphan pages (not linked to from anywhere) hosted on a domain. There needs to be a lead-to link for Google to access and index the page.

Comment: thanks @masmrdrr this helps a lot.. so i got it right, that you usually would need at least a directory or sitemap in the footer.. but is it possible to somehow hide it for users without getting in trouble with google?